# Telnet with Arduino & WiFi shield: connection refused

Tags: wireless, arduino, telnet

I've equipped an Arduino Due with a WiFi shield and want to run a Telnet server on the Arduino.
I've found here how to: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiChatServer
I copied the whole code and just changed SSID and the passphrase.

I'm aware of the fact that Telnet isn't a secure connection, but this is just for testing purposes.

When opening a terminal and entering

```
$telnet
$open 192.168.178.27
```

I get a "connection refused" as an answer.
I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 LTE
I already tried deactivating the firewall with

```
$sudo ufw disable
```

without success.

Can anybody help?
Sincerely,
Flap

Comment: I also updated the firmware, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the solution is the firmwareupdate since Arduino ships the WiFi chips with software from before 2012.
Now it works.